# Maven project for Spring WS, JAXB/XSD to create server WAR/EAR and client JAR, also autogenerate classes from XSD

Tags: soap, maven, jaxb, spring-ws

It may be difficult to explain exactly what I want, so please let me do step-by-step.

Our company has long-lived Java project that uses Spring WS, XSD files to generate WSDL and those beans from WSDL. Project is compiled/built using ANT with various targets (one target to generate classes from XSD, another to generate client JAR, another to generate Server WAR/EAR). This project used to run SOAP server and also used to generate client side JAR. But there is no single source of code anymore and number of pre-generated client JARs are flying around. I need to clean this mess using Maven.

I created modular Maven project, but basically the only real child project is one that contains all the custom code, all XSDs, etc (another child project simply packages EAR from the WAR generated by first project). Since this project uses Spring WS the final WSDL file is generated dynamically when run on server.

What I have managed so far is to do following:

- generate classes from XSD manually, add those classes to the /src/main/java so that they are stored permanently, have Maven to generate the rest of Service side architecture (WAR/EAR).
- separately using the WSDL file imported from running server generate Client JAR file by using eclipse WTP plugin (create new project, drop the WSDL into it, use WTP plugin to generate files, then export project into final JAR file) and then distribute this JAR to interested parties.

This works, but as you see the process of code maintenance has problem (pregenerated classes are included into the main source), the process of generating client is at best detached from the main project. So it is a mess I would like to be able to clean up.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

- create Maven project that hosts XSD files
- use it to generate classes and Client JAR
- refer to this project from Server side project so that the generated classes can be referenced by server side code
- the server side project is the one that would use Spring WS and that would be able to generate EAR file

The issue I am facing is simple: the XSD files to generate WSDL dynamically should really reside in that server project, not in client project. These files need to be in /src/main/resources so they are moved to class path of built WAR/EAR file. I could use two different copies of XSD - one on client side project another on server side project, but it sounds wrong.

So my main question really is - how do I approach this project architecture using Maven so that I only use single instance of any source file (XSD, Java, etc) and I am able to conveniently generate classes from XSD, build Client JAR and server WAR/EAR. I am OK with two or more separate build commands - one generates JAR, another generate EAR from proper project sources.

Oh by the way - refactoring the XSD files is out of question - they are given to us and must be used AS IS.

Thanks,
Nikolay

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate project for the just XSDs and build another JAR with just the classes generated from the XSDs.  You end up having 3 projects:

- XSD schema project
- client JAR
- server project

where the client JAR and server projects have a dependency on the XSD schema project.

You can build the whole thing in one go by using a parent project with all these projects as [child modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

If you are concerned that your client JAR is now actually two JARs (plus possibly more dependencies) you can use the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to bundle the contents of the XSD schema project's JAR in your client JAR.

Creating more projects/modules is almost always better than duplicating code.

---

Edit: To generate classes from WSDLs and XML Schema, you can use the [Maven JAX-WS plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) (wsimport goal) and/or the [Maven JAXB plugin](http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb-maven2-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks for the good reference (shade), it may help to bundle the final JAR/EAR files. I will still need to figure how to generate wsdl (tdrury@ has suggestion) and figure out how to autogenerate the actual SOAP client - remember I said we use Eclipse's WTP plugin to do that? It actually generates some stubs which used to call the server, not only the classes from WSDL. I would love to have that autogeneration to be invoked by Maven as well. Thanks for  your input!

Comment: @Nikolay added link to JAX-WS/JAXB plugins, they should help with generating classes from WSDL/XML Schema.

Comment: It turns out all our web client use Service Client generated using AXIS. The JAX-WS from jax-ws-commons is using other libraries therefore making generated client JAR incompatible with axis. I have to find way to use axis.

Comment: I have found this rather outdated plugin that uses what seems to be version 1 of axis: org.codehaus.mojo -> axistools-maven-plugin version 1.4. It does exactly what WTP plugin for eclipse does as far as generation of code/stubs down to the last package/subpackage name. At least I am now able to generate the client JAR off of just the wsdl ( not xsd files as wanted) by maven, without using eclipse+plugin. This matches to our numerous existent client JARs distributed everywhere through the company's code base.

Comment: I think I would prefer to use maven-jaxb2-plugin instead to generate beans off of XSD directly, but this one does not generate client stubs, only beans. Another plugin jaxws-maven-plugin, mentioned by prunge@, actually does generate the stubs and beans, but it also takes wsdl instead of xsd files (at least it is able to download wsdl from the provided url). But because it generates completely different client code, I cannot use it at the moment. I may like to switch to this plugin in the future. Thanks, Nikolay P.S. I still have to complete the Server side code, but this is more familiar task

Answer (score 0):

We generate quite a bit of code from XSDs.  Because we didn't want duplicate code, we use XML catalogs and a custom schema resolver which can resolve schemas from the classpath; I'm fairly sure apache has a schema resolver that will do this too - I remember finding it after we wrote ours.  In this way one module can reference the schema from another module's artifact by declaring it as a dependency.

Comment: Are  you suggesting to use that schema resolver to generate the final wsdl on the running server? We currently use Spring's CommonsXsdSchemaCollection which implements XsdSchemaCollection from Apache. I will check if this class can actually look up the class path instead of file location (which we currently use) to get the source XSD files. If this works, this could be our solution! Thanks

Comment: How do you generate a WSDL from a schema?  This aspect of your question confuses me.

Comment: Spring does at run time. I suppose the CommonsXsdSchemaCollection class (or some other bean) is responsible for that since it is configured as bean with those XSDs. I inherited this project and still going through trying to figure out how to improve